# Freeing Non-Jewish Slave

Tags: talmud-gemara, slave-serve-eved-avadim, tractate-brachot

I stumbled across this statement regarding the prohibition of freeing a non-Jewish slave in an online article quoting Gemara Brachos. I am just looking for some clarity and background as to the nature of this prohibition.

“The Talmud (Berachot 47b) states that Rabbi Eliezer once freed a non-Jewish slave, thus granting him the status of a full-fledged Jew, so that he could be the tenth man in a minyan. He did this, despite the prohibition of freeing a non-Jewish slave, because of the importance of the mitzvah of minyan.”

Answer (score 7):

It is a ‘prohibition’ derived from the positive command implied by [Vayikra 25:46](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.25.46?with=all&lang=bi&aliyot=0):

> לעולם בהם תעבדו
>
> For all time shall you treat them as slaves

See [Sefer HaChinuch 347](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sefer_HaChinukh.347?lang=bi) for details.